Alkali-rich lead glass with working range at room temperature
I understand that the glass transition temperature (above which it is considered a super-cooled liquid) is quite far below the liquidus of the corresponding crystalline mixture. In the paper, "Relation between apparent glass transition temperature and liquids temperature for inorganic glasses" (DOI: 10.1016/0022-3093(71)90053-6), it is suggested that the two temperatures have a ratio of 2/3 (in Kelvin most likely).
I also know that $\ce{Li2O-}$, $\ce{Na2O-}$, $\ce{K2O-}$, and $\ce{PbO-SiO2}$ systems have a eutectic point close to pure $\ce{SiO2}$ which has a melting point at or under about 800 degrees Celsius.
Based on the ratio, the glass transition temperature for each of the eutectic would be about 400 C. Possibly, $\ce{Rb2O}$ and $\ce{Cs2O}$ could have the same effect, but I could not find any phase diagrams. Other oxides, such as alumina, calcia, and magnesia only lower the melting point to above 1000 C.
In other words, Is there a glass composition with a low enough glass transition temperature so that the working range is within room temperature?





This paper, "PHASE DIAGRAMS OF SILICATE SYSTEMS: HANDBOOK; THIRD ISSUE; TERNARY SYSTEMS" does give some ternary phase diagrams.
